# VSCode & Git Bash tagging

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I try to tag my sample project from the command line

```
git tag -a v1.0
```

I applied this from Git Bash or VSCode Integrated Terminal and the following issue appears:

> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...

I have the configuration of the git for `core.editor=code --wait -n`

How should I properly configure git to avoid such issues?

Comment: Does your system start a new instance of VSCode ? If yes : type your message in that other instance, save & quit.

Comment: For each time I apply tagging from Git Bash then VSCode is started.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe matches the expected behavior of `code --wait -n` : `-n` instructs vscode to open a new instance, `--wait` instructs vscode to return only once the opened tab has been closed.

---

If you want to allow opening message edition as a tab of an already running instance of vscode, just drop the `-n` :

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

You will still have the "hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file..." mesage, but that time, this editor can be a tab in your current instance of vscode.
Just save and close the tab to indicate to git "I am done".

Comment: Did change "git config", and by applying the tag I added "-m "ready"" and now works :)

Comment: ok. Note that, if you provide a message with `-m "..."`, the editor will not be opened anyway -- in that case the configuration setting has no impact.